# Should one be able to contact a down voter (without knowing the down voter's identity of course)?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes

I've come across an incident, more than once, where I posted a rather bad question and got down-voted for it, and I would say deservedly as well. However, I then took it upon myself to thoroughly edit the question, and now I no longer believe it is worth the initial down-votes it got, but at the same time I do not believe it should be up-voted either. I simply believe that the down-votes should be reversed. Unfortunately, there is no way for me to call the attention of a random down-voter, to let them know that the question has been re-edited, and that perhaps it is no longer deserving of the bad rep it originally got.

Do you think it would be a good idea to have the asker be able to call the attention of a down-voter, maybe through the press of an `NOTIFY` button (which of course he can only use once, so as not to abuse it), that notifies the down-voters  that the question should be reviewed once more, and that the down-votes should be reconsidered?

Note: If something similar already exists on SO, please let me know how it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Such a feature would be abused horribly. There's a natural tendency, upon facing criticism, to attack the critic - this rarely ends well.

See: [@Downvoter sends a notification to all downvoters for your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post)

A related long-standing request has been for a mechanism allowing voters to *find out* when a post they'd downvoted has been edited, without being *contacted* as such. A potentially-workable solution is outlined here: [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: "I think I've fixed the issue now - please check"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c/157699#157699)

Comment: but we have mechanisms for reporting abuse or may need better ones. This happens in the outside world all the time. Also if someone tries to go too far then they'll be (most probably) apprehended and taken care of. I also believe if someone is brave enough to voice their opinion or point fingers, then they should be ready to embrace the consequences and face the reactions (not endorsing the inappropriate ones just suggesting they are not avoidable and very much possible) because basically freedom of speech and the way it's wished for, is more or less an illusion and an ideal.

Answer (score 3):

If the question has been improved to the point of being a good one, surely someone will come along and recognize that it is a good question, and give it an upvote. No need for the downvoter to have to come back and check that you've done your homework: they've already done their part by giving you the spur to improve your question.